# How to allow user to run the eval command on mongodb 2.6

Tags: mongodb, eval

As described in docs, I have to create a role that allows anyAction on anyResource, but this role can be created only in admin database, so this is how it looks like:

```
use admin
db.createRole({
    role: 'superuser',
    privileges:[{
        resource: {anyResource: true},
        actions: ['anyAction']
    }],
    roles: []
})
```

Next step is to grant this role to a user, but here is the problem, I can't grant the role from admin database to user from another database, so this command:

```
db.createUser({
    user: 'someusername',
    pwd: 'somepassword',
    roles: [{
        role: 'superuser',
        db: 'somedatabase'
    }]
})
```

returns as expected:

```
Error: couldn't add user: No role named superuser@somedatabase
```

So, what should I do to allow user someusername to run eval command on somedatabase?

Answer (score 4):

So, the problem was in incorrect roles list. The correct one is:

```
db.createUser({
    user: 'someusername',
    pwd: 'somepassword',
    roles: ['superuser']
})
```

Comment: [This](http://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/555/allow-mongodb-user-execute-command-eval-mongodb-3.x#.VcpQ6_ntlBc) was also helpful for me.